# How to configure a module fallback path for a specific module?

Tags: webpack

My webpack project depends on a dependency "apple" (made up name). "apple" dependency is relying on `NODE_PATH` to be set to `NODE_PATH=/path/to/apple-module`. If you are not familiar with this approach, read [How I Work Around The require(“../../../../../../../”) Problem In NodeJS](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/02/20/how-i-work-around-the-require-problem-in-nodejs/) (I do not endorse this approach.)

I do not have any control over "apple" module.

`webpack` allows to configure `fallback` path, which when set to `/path/to/apple-module` makes "apple" module resolution work. However, this approach puts at risk the entire application module resolution logic.

Is there a way to set a fallback path that is applied only for a specific module?

Here is an example of a public module using this pattern:

https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js/blob/51c068bed4e78ba5db7f44911f7ae8ef259f692f/dist/common/formatter.js#L8-L10

```
var patternMatcher = require('pattern-matcher');
var inptSel = require('inpt-sel');
var utils = require('utils');
```

Notice that "pattern-matcher", "inpt-sel" and "utils" are [not dependencies](https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js/blob/51c068bed4e78ba5db7f44911f7ae8ef259f692f/package.json) of the package. These are files inlcuded in the [`./common` path](https://github.com/firstopinion/formatter.js/tree/51c068bed4e78ba5db7f44911f7ae8ef259f692f/dist/common). As a result, I am getting an error:

```
ERROR in ./~/formatter.js/dist/common/formatter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pattern-matcher' in 'c:\Dev\repositories\krypton\kwak-client\node_modules\formatter.js\dist\common'
 @ ./~/formatter.js/dist/common/formatter.js 11:21-47

ERROR in ./~/formatter.js/dist/common/formatter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'inpt-sel' in 'c:\Dev\repositories\krypton\kwak-client\node_modules\formatter.js\dist\common'
 @ ./~/formatter.js/dist/common/formatter.js 12:14-33

ERROR in ./~/formatter.js/dist/common/formatter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utils' in 'c:\Dev\repositories\krypton\kwak-client\node_modules\formatter.js\dist\common'
 @ ./~/formatter.js/dist/common/formatter.js 13:12-28
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I get it right, but it seems you need to rely on webpack aliases, see https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#aliasing

Comment: This is just for setting an alias of the module within the application itself. The problem is when the module attempts to `require('conf/example.json')`, which it expects to resolve to `./node_modules/apple/conf/example.json`, and it would if `NODE_PATH` is set. But this setup does not work in webpack setup. Thus the question.